# Search endpoint with ViewSet & Routers in Django-REST-FrameWork

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

> Views.py

```
class ClientViewSet(ModelViewSet, GetOrRaiseMixin):
    serializer_class = ClientSerializer
    queryset = Client.objects.all()

    def list(self, request):
        serializer = ClientSerializer(self.queryset, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=HTTP_200_OK, safe=False)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        client = self.get_or_raise('Client', pk)
        serializer = ClientSerializer(client)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=HTTP_200_OK)

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = ClientSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid'}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
        client = self.get_or_raise('Client', pk)
        client.datetime_deleted = datetime.now()
        client.save()
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

> Urls.py

```
router.register('clients', ClientViewSet, base_name='clients')
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

> PROBLEM

Above works great for standard behaviour like create / retrieve_all / retrieve_by_id / update_by_id / delete_by_id.
But what I want is to add an additional enpoint for search_&_retrieve.

For example:

> /api/clients/search/?title='John'&age='32' etc.

So generally I need 5 endpoints: Create/Retrieve/Update/Delete/Search.

Can I achieve that with "ViewSet+Routers" concept or I need to do something else ?

> UPDATE

I also had to remove the "list" function in my ClientViewSet class to make this endpoint work:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/clients/?title=John&age=32
```

I don't know why, but when you define the "list" function explicitly, a search endpoint just return every record from DB instead of filtering it, so be aware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `django-filter` library for this:

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

class ClientViewSet(ModelViewSet, GetOrRaiseMixin):
    serializer_class = ClientSerializer
    queryset = Client.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('title', 'age')
```

Check this [part](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend) of DRF documentation for quickstart.

Comment: I made a GET request like: http://localhost:8000/api/clients?title=John&age=32 (And I really have that object in my DB) but I got: "Could not get any response"

Comment: @Madi7 what is GetOrRaiseMixin? Probably it raise some error? Do you see any errors in console?

Comment: I simply returns an object if it exists in DB or raise JsonResponse with message that object does not exist, it definately does not cause trouble

Comment: I'm getting response 301

Comment: @Madi7 try  localhost:8000/api/clients/?title=John&age=32 with slash before &.

Comment: Man, you are a lifesaver, this is not the first time you're helping me, many thanks to you!

Comment: @Madi7 haha, you are welcome! Check `trailing_slash` part here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter this about slashes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding your own search endpoint (if you wanted full optimised search endpoint consider Haystack)

you could just modify `filter_class`, `filter_backends` and `search_fields` in your `ModelViewSet` which will handle it for you and are extendable